# How to make sure cucumber stops execution when a step fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Cucumber keeps executing even after a step definition has failed, and it outputs not only the failing steps, but also the passing ones. What option do I need to use in order to ensure that Cucumber stop executing as soon as it has encountered a failing step?

This is my cucumber.yml file

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
autotest: <%= std_opts %> features --color
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Use a [cucumber hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks):

```
After do |s| 
  # Tell Cucumber to quit after this scenario is done - if it failed.
  Cucumber.wants_to_quit = true if s.failed?
end
```

#### Or, raise an exception.

The recommended way is using a cucumber hook, though.

Answer (score 5):

As of Cucumber 2.1 you can pass the --fail-fast tag.

It should fail at the first scenario that fails and skip remaining scenarios.

Part of this PR https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/pull/906

Answer (score 4):

This lets fail fast be invoked from the command line:

```
# `FAST=1 cucumber` to stop on first failure
After do |scenario|
  Cucumber.wants_to_quit = ENV['FAST'] && scenario.failed?
end
```